# Need know which element get focus when another element lost focus

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-runtime, wpf-controls, winrt-xaml

I have many controls in a window. Requirement is to know which control gets the focus from the lost focus event of a control.

Say, A Text box and it has the focus. Now I am clicking a button. while doing this, need to know that i am moving the focus to button from the Text box lost focus event.

So how could i achieve this..

Comment: you could subscribe all controls to the same GetFocus event and verify the sender there

Comment: It is likely that the `lost focus` event will fire before the button even gets focus. You should consider that, or atleast confirm if it is true. It might be worth telling us what end goal you are trying to achieve, there may be an alternative approach

Comment: Agree with @musefan, **It might be worth telling us what end goal you are trying to achieve, there may be an alternative approach**.

Comment: @musefan: my requirement is, i have a custom control and that control has various controls like textbox in its Template. Now the focus is in one of the textbox and i need to know, which control gets focus while this control lost the focus. by that i can hold the focus in the textbox itself when it was clicked away from the custom control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following class watches the FocusManager for changes in focus, it's a looped thread so you have to put up with the fact that it's running but when focus changes it will just raise an event letting you know what changed.

Just add these two classes to your project.

```
    public class FocusNotifierEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public object OldObject { get; set; }
        public object NewObject { get; set; }
    }

    public class FocusNotifier : IDisposable
    {
        public event EventHandler<FocusNotifierEventArgs> OnFocusChanged;
        bool isDisposed;
        Thread focusWatcher;
        Dispatcher dispatcher;
        DependencyObject inputScope;
        int tickInterval;

        public FocusNotifier(DependencyObject inputScope, int tickInterval = 10)
        {
            this.dispatcher = inputScope.Dispatcher;
            this.inputScope = inputScope;
            this.tickInterval = tickInterval;
            focusWatcher = new Thread(new ThreadStart(FocusWatcherLoop))
            {
                Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal,
                Name = "FocusWatcher"
            };
            focusWatcher.Start();
        }

        IInputElement getCurrentFocus()
        {
            IInputElement results = null;
            Monitor.Enter(focusWatcher);
            dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    Monitor.Enter(focusWatcher);
                    results = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(inputScope);
                    Monitor.Pulse(focusWatcher);
                    Monitor.Exit(focusWatcher);
                }));
            Monitor.Wait(focusWatcher);
            Monitor.Exit(focusWatcher);
            return results;
        }

        void FocusWatcherLoop()
        {
            object oldObject = null;
            while (!isDisposed)
            {
                var currentFocus = getCurrentFocus();
                if (currentFocus != null)
                {
                     if (OnFocusChanged != null)
                        dispatcher.BeginInvoke(OnFocusChanged, new object[]{ this,  new FocusNotifierEventArgs()
                        {
                            OldObject = oldObject,
                            NewObject = currentFocus
                        }});
                    oldObject = currentFocus;
                    }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(tickInterval);
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (!isDisposed)
            {
                isDisposed = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then in your code behind, create a new instance of the Focus Notifier class and hook on to it's OnFocusChanged event, remember to dispose it at the end or the thread will keep your app open.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    FocusNotifier focusNotifier;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        focusNotifier = new FocusNotifier(this);
        focusNotifier.OnFocusChanged += focusNotifier_OnFocusChanged;
    }

    void focusNotifier_OnFocusChanged(object sender, FocusNotifierEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.OldObject);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.NewObject);

    }

    protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        focusNotifier.Dispose();
        base.OnClosing(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did and its working for me

```
 protected override void OnPreviewLostKeyboardFocus(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
   {
     lostFocusControl = e.OldFocus;
   }

   private void PauseBttn_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   {
      /**invoke OnPreviewLostKeyboardFocus handller**/
   }
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

You can use FocusManager to handle this,
In your LostFocusEvent, Use FocusManager.GetFocusedElement()

```
uiElement.LostFocus+=(o,e)=>
{
      var foo=FocusManager.GetFocusedElement();
}
```

Comment: This will gives the current element. I need to know the element which is going to get the focus.

Comment: nop, GetFocusedElement returns the new element where you clicked :-) Checked with a Simple Sample ;-)

Comment: This is the easiest and most correct answer in my opinion. Thanks!

Comment: My textbox with AcceptsTab=true is set to handle PreviewKeyDown to switch focus to a listbox (with e.Handled=true), but although this executes, the stackpanel containing both still executes LostFocus returning null for .GetFocusedElement(), passing that stackpanel to the element.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to register your controls to Control.LostFocus event and there you can check for Form.ActiveControl, to determine which control currently has the focus